# The revisions table in my database is at 70% capacity and growing. What should I do?

Tags: database

I installed the [Wordpress System Health Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-system-health/) and it says that the revisions table in my database is at 70% capacity with 994 rows.  I don't fully understand what this means.  I anticipate that my site will get much larger than it is today.

Questions

- Am I going to run into trouble or is there some way I can increase that table's capacity?
- Is it a hosting issue?

One proactive thing I have done is set a max number of post revisions to 4.

Any solution or an explanation to help me understand what's going on would be really appreciated.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL query to run via phpmyadmin

```
DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id) WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'
```

That query will remove all post revisions from your wp database,, **But remember always back up your database before running any direct SQL query..**

you can also add a line into wp_config.php that will disable revisions (optional, i use it as i find revisions a bit of a pain)

`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);`

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible it's telling you that 994 rows equal 70% of the total data in your database? I'm not sure what "70% capacity" means, MySQL has a memory limit of several gigabytes for a single database and can handle millions of records.